# I am getting the following error "source option 5 is no longer supported .use 7 or later"

Tags: java, maven

my pom.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.bharath</groupId>
  <artifactId>hellomaven</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>hellomaven</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

I am getting the following error

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project hellomaven: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:

[ERROR] Source option 5 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later.

[ERROR] Target option 5 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later.

[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

if i try by adding below code to my pom.xml file

```
<properties>
<maven.compiler.source>16</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>16</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

i am getting below error

The project  (C:\Users\DODDI GIRISH\hellomaven\pom.xml) has 1 error
Non-parseable POM C:\Users\DODDI GIRISH\hellomaven\pom.xml: start tag not allowed in epilog but got p (position: END_TAG seen ...\r\n\r\n<p... @19:3)  @ line 19, column 3 ->
my properties code starts from 19th line.
my entire pom.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.bharath</groupId>
  <artifactId>hellomaven</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>hellomaven</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
<properties>
   <maven.compiler.source>16</maven.compiler.source>
   <maven.compiler.target>16</maven.compiler.target>
 </properties>
```

help me with this.

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share the entire pom.xml after attempting to add the `properties` section? It seems like you've mistakenly created an invalid XML file

Comment: added pom.xml file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.bharath</groupId>
  <artifactId>hellomaven</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>hellomaven</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Properties should be inside the project!!!

```
<properties>
   <maven.compiler.source>16</maven.compiler.source>
   <maven.compiler.target>16</maven.compiler.target>
 </properties>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
.
.
.
<properties>
   <maven.compiler.source>16</maven.compiler.source>
   <maven.compiler.target>16</maven.compiler.target>
 </properties>
</project>
```

Properties should be inside project

Answer (score 1):

It seems that if you don't specify a compiler Maven resorts to using a default compiler. If you don't have that installed then you're going to have issues. The course I was following omitted the `<properties></properties>` tags from their POM files. I had to add these (inside the `<project></project>` tags) to stop mvn throwing the 'Source option 5 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later.' exception.

This link is informative...

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/

...from which we learn...

> Also note that at present the default source setting is 1.7 and the
> default target setting is 1.7, independently of the JDK you run Maven
> with. You are highly encouraged to change these defaults by setting
> source and target as described in Setting the -source and -target of
> the Java Compiler.

A quick check at the command line...

```
java --version
java 18.0.2 2022-07-19
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 18.0.2+9-61)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 18.0.2+9-61, mixed mode, sharing)
```

..and...

```
mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.8.6 (84538c9988a25aec085021c365c560670ad80f63)
Maven home: C:\apache-maven-3.8.6
Java version: 18.0.2, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-18.0.2
Default locale: en_GB, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

...so, although Maven and Java appear to be in harmony, Maven's default source/target settings requires a mod to the POM file...

```
<properties>
   <maven.compiler.source>18</maven.compiler.source>
   <maven.compiler.target>18</maven.compiler.target>
 </properties>
```

...and we're up and running.

Alternatively we could modify the compiler plugin.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>18</source>
                <target>18</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

You may also want to investigate setting up a master/super POM if you have multiple projects hanging off of a single root directory.